# [Class].class.getResourceAsStream(...) returns null when used in JAR files in certain directories?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I have a very strange problem. It appears that loading resources from inside a JAR file sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

The Jar file consists only of the class files, the manifest and the `test.txt`.

When I pack it with Eclipse, it usually works well (the contents of test.txt can be accessed) but in some directories, the `Resourceproblem.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")` returns `null` - although it's the same Jar file!

For example when I double click the jar file `\\remotecomputer\folder\subfolder\test.jar` the `test.txt` inside the jar file could not be found. But it's also sometimes (?) the case when the path name is very long and contains spaces (at least on Windows XP SP3).

Any ideas?

Sample code:

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Resourceproblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Resourceproblem();
            }
        });
    }

    private Resourceproblem() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        text.setEditable(false);
        frame.add(text);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            InputStream in = Resourceproblem.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = br.readLine();
            br.close();
            in.close();
            text.setText(line);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            ex.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.flush();
            String s = sw.toString();
            pw.close();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            text.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

test.txt ist just a text file with a line for checking if the loading was successful.

Comment: I think you need to read up on the difference between the various ways of accessing the classloader, namely the difference between [`getClass().getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) and [`ClassLoader.getResourceAtStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Boris: What exactly do you mean by that? When I try `Resourceproblem.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");` it doesn't even work in Eclipse anymore.

Comment: Well that implies that your file isn't where you think it is.

Comment: Check that the .jar file actually has test.txt in it.  A .jar file is actually a .zip file, so you can open it with any tool that reads .zip files.  You can even copy it, rename the copy to have a .zip extension, and open it using Windows' built-in zip handler.

Comment: @VGR: Yes it has the test.txt in it. As I wrote, this works in MOST directories, but in some "special" (?) directories, it just doesn't.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the problem: When you say "works in most directories," do you mean that it works most of the time, but `getResourceAsStream` returns null when the .jar file is located in a UNC path?

Comment: @VGR: As long as it's not in one of the "special" directories, it will load just fine every time. But in some - like UNC paths - it can never find the resource and returns `null`.

Comment: You might get a hint of what the problem is by calling `getResource` to get the `URL` used to read the resource and see if there is anything odd about that. `getResourceAsStream` just calls `getResource` and then calls `URL.openStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but I have little confidence that I know what your problem is.

I used eclipse to create a jar file from your example source several times; I stored the jar file in c:\local and in c:\local\one\two three\four, using Win7.

I am unfamiliar with the use of "/" at the front of the resource filename in the getResourceAsStream() call.  Your sample program worked in each case either with or without the "/", but I would recommend removing it and seeing if that solves your problem.  The file, in that case, goes in the same directory as the class that is accessing it.

I would have thought that the "/" would cause the program to look for the file at the root directory of the file system, but that doesn't seem to happen...

Comment: "I have no idea how `ClassLoader`'s work so here's a random guess"? Not really an answer. `/` means the root of the classpath, it has very little to do with which directory your jar in located in.

Comment: The "/" is just for loading resources from within the JAR. Without it, the resource cannot be loaded at all.

Comment: No -- I took off the "/", created the jar, ran it in eclipse, created the jar with eclipse, moved the jar to the two directories I mentioned, and it loaded that file just fine from the jar.

Comment: @rcook: I think I now finally understood what you meant. I was talking about a JAR file containing the class files AND the test.txt, while you thought about having the test.txt separately, right?

Comment: No -- the "root directory of the file system" part of my answer is probably misleading. I have since researched this and found that, for getResourceAsStream, "/" is the "top" of the jar file, i.e., if you look for /a/b/c/test.txt, it is expected to be in those folders within the jar.  If you leave off the "/", then you are specifying things relative to the folder/package in which the class you are using lives, i.e. "a/b/c/test.txt" using getResource from class x.y.z.MyClass indicates the file is in x/y/z/a/b/c.

Comment: @rcook: So the / is correct, because the test.txt is in the root folder of the JAR.

Comment: @Ayce: and your statement including "cannot be loaded at all" is incorrect. Glad we got it straight, finally.